# Maximum likelihood - random walk with noise measurement

Tags: statistics, random-walk, maximum-likelihood, kalman-filter

Let us consider a random walk:

$$x_{t+1} = x_t + \sigma e_{t+1}, x_0 = 0.$$

Let us consider the observable random variable:

$$y_t = x_t + \nu \eta_t.$$

We assume that $(e_t)$ and $(\eta_t)$ are independent, iid, and standard Normal.

Can we explicitly find the maximum likelihood estimators of $\sigma$ and $\nu$ (we only observe the $y$s)?

Comment: Take a look at how Kalman filter is applied in the context of likelihood estimation for linear state space models.

Comment: @Calculon, can you give me a reference? For me Kalman filter is for fixed $\sigma$. Anything good to read on adaptive Kalman filters then?

Comment: Your formulation does not mention varying $\sigma$. The book of Brockett on time series has a chapter on Kalman filter. One of the sections is precisely about the problem you want to solve.

Comment: Can you give the reference of the book? Google does not really help

Comment: Oh sorry it was Brockwell. https://www.springer.com/gb/book/9780387974293

Comment: Thx. I have gone through the chapter on KF. Unfortunately, my question seems not to be adressed. I want to find the MLE of $\sigma$ and $\nu$ (i.e. $Q$ and $R$ in Kalman filter vocabulary).

Comment: Section 12.3. The expression right above eqn 12.3.1.

Comment: This is the expression for the likelihood, not the expression of the MLE. My problem comes from the fact that the first order condition seems impossible to solve explicitly.

Comment: You did not mention that. If you write out the likelihood function for your example in your question, maybe others can point out whether you can maximize it analytically. MLE does not always have an analytical solution.